# retrieve a `char *` returned from C function exported from .so in Python

Tags: python, c

I got a `liba.so` containing a function `say_hi()`,

```
char *say_hi()
{
    return "hello, world";
}
```

In Python, I accessed `liba.so` via `ctypes`,

```
>>>liba = ctypes.CDLL("./liba.so")
>>>liba.say_hi()
16422018
```

How can I retrieve the string `"hello, world"` returned by `liba.say_hi()` in Python?

**PS**

Besides `restype`, any other way?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#return-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs of Python ctypes-modules offers type-casting functions. Eg. [c_char_p](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#ctypes.c_char_p):

> Represents the C char * datatype when it points to a zero-terminated string. For a general character pointer that may also point to binary data, POINTER(c_char) must be used. **The constructor accepts an integer address, or a bytes object.**

So try this:

```
ctypes.c_char_p( liba.say_hi() )
```

**PS:** It builds immutable strings. For mutable ones look at [create_string_buffer](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#ctypes.create_string_buffer)
There are also some self-descriptive exameples on the page.

Answer (score 3):

Does this answer your question?

http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#return-types

Comment: Indeed, it does. :-), well besides `restype`, any other way?

Comment: Why is it necessary? Python can't infer types from C. The best answer is just to tell python what the return type is. That is probably the best way to do it in nearly every case.

Comment: Thanks, just seeking other ways to do the job, seems this is the best way.